# Change the search URL

Tags: url-rewriting, search

How can I change the search URL from /?s=my-word to **/busca/?s=my-word** ?

I know how to change to /busca/my-word, but I really need the "s" parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [WPEngineer](http://wpengineer.com/2258/change-the-search-url-of-wordpress/) (with edits):

Add the following to functions.php in your theme:

```
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/busca/?s=" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

Add the following to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /busca/%1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

**Note: Code is untested**

**Edit: Minor modifications made to answer the question more thoroughly**

Comment: But I need the ?s= parameter, I need something like: /busca/?s=my-word

Comment: Minor modifications to this code should be able to accomplish what you're asking. Just a sec.

Comment: When I tried I got just 404.

Comment: Give the new code a try.

Comment: Sorry, but I still got 404.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to work extending this code yourself.